# Flutter: from bottomModal to fullscreen page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am looking to create in Flutter a modal dialog that slides in from the bottom and

1. Appears with a given height (eg. 1/3 of the screen)
2. Expands vertically if the user scrolls up on it (and shrinks until disappearing if the user scrolls down)
3. Provides some kind of callback or observable so that I can know when it reaches the top of the screen/parent. (I need this in order to create a back arrow on the top left corner of the panel itself)

Is there any way to achieve this?
I have found the package [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) to be really nice, but lacking the third feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SlidingUpPanel` does actually have everything you need. You want to use the `onPanelSlide` property from it which will provide you the current % opened of the panel normalized (`[0, 1.0]`), so if you want to know when it reaches the top you, it's when its current position is at `1.0`.

As an alternative, you may want to take a look at [`DraggableScrollableSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html) widget, but IMO, `SlidingUpPanel` is more versatile.